# Questions about locking down Windows Store Apps with Software Restriction GPO

Tags: windows, group-policy, restrictions, software-update

A software restriction GPO has been configured and applied to a test environment with the following rules:

%programfiles%\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore* - Disallowed - For Windows 10 Pro
With this setting, every time a user attempts to load the Windows Store application, they're met with a blocked application prompt. Which is good - we don't want users to be able to download apps.

**There's a few unanswered questions/potential issues I have with this:**

1. Patch management: Software must be patched within 14 days of an
   update being released, where the patch fixes a * vulnerability with
   a severity the product vendor describes as ‘critical’ or ‘high risk’
   *

   Will any of the applications (such as Skype) receive any updates
   after re-applying the software restriction policy?

   Notes: When enabled, the user cannot access this directory: 
   %programfiles%\WindowsApps\
2. Can an exception be made to allow specific application (Skype), and
   block the rest?
   enter code here
3. Is there a better way of doing this within a Windows 10 Pro
   environment?

Comment: "Will any of the applications (such as Skype) receive any updates after re-applying the software restriction policy?" - The UWP version of Skype should only be updated if action is taken by the user to update it.  "Is there a better way of doing this within a Windows 10 Pro environment?" - Use the desktop version of Skype.  "When enabled, the user cannot access this directory" - A user can't access the contents of any of the folders contained in `../WindowsApps` by default regardless.